# How to make a infinite list of bools in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, switch-statement, toggle

I created a switch(toggle button) in flutter which is wrapped inside of a card which is inside of a list view. I am trying to make an alarm app so the number of cards added is infinite/unknown.
How can I make a list of bools which is already infinite so that a new bool is added and the number of bool items autoincrements/deletes as an alarm is added?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you show your code. and what does `already infinite` means?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I get you true but if you want to define a list with growable size then use;

```
List <bool> liste = [];
```

Whenever you want to add some bool to end of list;

```
liste.add(true);
```

Also check ;

[infinitelistview](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_listview)

Comment: Thanks but I found the problem and it was really easy:). Just make a separate widget file and make a switch in a stateful widget and then call that switch where you want it to display.